# why does this jquery not run in ie7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I'm new to jQuery and have managed to cut and paste together the following script:

http://jsfiddle.net/tbfHF/4/

It basically takes the value of the input box and inserts into another generated element along with a link that should delete the item when clicked. Now it does almost what I need it to except for in IE where it appears that the script does not run at all. Anyone who can help with fixing that? And also help with wrapping the two generated elements (the text field and the X link) in a div so that the generated structure would be

```
<div class="regItm">
  <input properties.../><a properties...>X</a>
</div>
<div class="regItm">
  <input properties.../><a properties...>X</a>
</div>
...
...
```

--> UPDATE EDIT
I've removed the commas so now it works in IE as well but the wrapping of the divs still remains, anyone who can show how that is done?

here is the updated version http://jsfiddle.net/tbfHF/13/

Comment: IE7 doesn't speak Swedish. True story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE7 does not allow trailing commas after the last item in an object definition (other browsers don't object).  Remove the trailing comma in this:

```
.attr({value: regNum,})
```

and this:

```
{id: regNum,})
```

This fixed version runs in IE7: http://jsfiddle.net/tbfHF/11/

Comment: for what it's worth, this affects all versions of IE, not just IE7.

Comment: If I remember correctly, IE will bug out on trailing commas in arrays, too.

Comment: @Spudley - Actually, IE9 and IE10 will tolerate the extraneous commas.  It's just the older versions of IE (IE6-IE8) that have trouble.  They are technically incorrect anyway so they should be removed.  If I recall correctly, ECMA5 formally make the ending commas allowable (to try to get consistency).

Comment: Great, that fixes the IE7 issue, THX! Anyone who would like to try their hand on wrapping the elements?

Comment: @A.G. - I do not understand the other part of the question.  Perhaps that should be a separate question since it is completely different from what has already been answered.

Comment: This is one of those rare things where I think IE got it right and the other browsers are wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you're including the `type` property in the script tag:

`<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: I assumed he had some website and JSFiddle was just to isolate the bug.

Comment: The type is not even needed, much less not the issue here.